# How to install ApkInspector on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I want to install apkinspector on ubuntu 18.04. I found that I have to first install Qt as discussed on GitHub:
[Apkpector Installtion](https://github.com/honeynet/apkinspector)

For installing Qt I tried following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386

sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386

sudo apt install qtchooser
```

But when I am using

```
Qmake -v
```

I am getting following message:

> qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Somebody please guide  me.

Zulfi.

Comment: I think I installed Qt. I checked the GitHub link and found that I have to install to install and update some stuff. I tried following commands from GitHub:

Comment: I installed aptitude package and updated the /etc/profile but I got a large message which says at the end: This package should not be used for building Debian packages. Take a look
 at http://pkg-kde.alioth.debian.org/packagingqtbasedstuff.html for more
 information.
Homepage: http://qt-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the repository

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/honeynet/apkinspector.git
cd apkinspector
```

and then install all the dependencies from APT:

```
sudo apt install qt4-default python-sip python-qt4 python-pydot graphviz apktool python-tk python-scipy ipython
```

then you need to patch it as IPython internals were slightly changed:

```
sed -i "s/import IPython.ipapi/import IPython/g" androguard/androlyze.py
sed -i "s/from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed/#from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed/g" androguard/androlyze.py
```

then launch it and enjoy:

```
python startQT.py
```

> [image: ApkInspector on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS]